# How to integrate 3rd party javascript with turbo drive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, turbo-drive

I have a rails app using turbo. My live chat app breaks on any page navigation as the elements created for it are removed as the DOM refreshes. Is there a generally accepted solution to this?

Comment: https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/building#installing-javascript-behavior

Comment: I have the same issue, I have an inline 3rd party script that appends a widget to the parent as a sibling, but this only works on initial page load or a full page refresh. If I navigate using links, the widget doesn't render unless I disable Turbo (not an option).

Answer (score 1):

You can make a DOM element permanent with `data-turbo-permanent`.

For example:

```
<div id="cart-counter" data-turbo-permanent>1 item</div>
```

The cart counter will persist between page loads.

Check more information here https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/building#persisting-elements-across-page-loads